# How to factor $a^3 - b^3$?

Tags: factoring

I know the answer is $(a - b)(a^2 + ab + b^2)$, but how do I arrive there? The example in the book I'm following somehow broke down $a^3 - b^3$ into $a^3 - (a^2)b + (a^2)b - a(b^2) + a(b^2) - b^3$ and factored that into $(a-b)(a^2 + ab + b^2)$ from there, but I don't quite understand how it was done.

Comment: The expression is obviously 0 if $a=b$, so $a-b$ is a factor. It is now easy to divide $a^3-b^3$ by $a-b$ to get the other factor.

Comment: @almagest I don't understand? How do you divide (a^3 -b^3) by (a-b)?

Comment: The simplest way is probably to write $(a-b)(\lambda a^2+\mu ab+\nu b^2)$ and then to compare coefficients to find $\lambda,\mu,\nu$. Or you just keep subtracting multiples of $a-b$. So start by subtracting $a^2(a-b)$ to get rid of the $a^3$ term. That leaves $a^2b-b^3$. Now subtract $ab(a-b)$ to get rid of the $a^2b$ term. That leaves $ab^2-b^3$. Subtracting $b^2(a-b)$ leaves 0.

Comment: @MoHagos $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)a^2+ba^2-b^3=(a-b)a^2+(a-b)ba+b^2a-b^3$$

$$=(a-b)a^2+(a-b)ba+(a-b)b^2=(a-b)\left(a^2+ab+b^2\right)$$

Comment: $$a^3 - b^3=(a^3 - a^2b) + (a^2b - ab^2)+ (ab^2 - b^3)=a^2(a-b)+a(a-b)b+(a-b)b^2=\ldots$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long division makes it as easy as $1$, $2$, $3$:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{a^3-b^3}{a-b}&=a^2+\frac{ba^2-b^3}{a-b} \tag 1\\\\
&=a^2+ab+\frac{b^2a-b^3}{a-b} \tag 2\\\\
&=a^2+ab+b^2 \tag 3
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Note that in $(1)$, the term $\frac{ba^2-b^3}{a-b}$ is the remainder of $a^2$ in $\frac{a^3-b^3}{a-b}$.

Note that in $(2)$, the term $\frac{b^2a-b^3}{a-b}$ is the remainder of $ab$ in $\frac{ba^2-b^3}{a-b}$.

Note that in $(3)$ the remainder is zero after dividing $b^2a-b^3$ by $a-b$.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  Pleased that this was useful.  -Mark