# How is $f(x) = x^2|x|$ differentiable for $c > 0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, absolute-value

What I've gotten so far is the following.

Let $f(x) = x^2|x|$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable at every point. $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} =\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^{2}|x|}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0}x|x|$ = $x^2 \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$. So, $f(x)$ is differentiable at $0$.

I was wondering how I prove that $f(x)$ is differentiable for $c > 0$ ?

Comment: For $x > 0$, $f(x) = x^2 \cdot x = x^3$. For $x<0$, $f(x) = -x^3$.

Comment: you mean $x>0$?

Comment: but how do I show that $x^3$ is differentiable?

Comment: The fact that $x^3$ is differentiable follows pretty quickly from the limit definition.

Comment: @Thomas, in my notes it says $c > 0$ even though $x$ is used.

Comment: I wanted to prove it showing that $\lim{x \to c}\frac{x^3-c^3}{x-c}$ and then simplify from there, but I'm having a hard time doing that.

Comment: @Sharon: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730596/simplifying-the-expression-fracx3-y3x-y, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789286/how-to-factor-a3-b3.

Comment: @MartinR. So then $\lim_{x \to c} = x^2 -xc  + c^2$?

Comment: There is a mistake in your proof. $x|x| = \pm x^2$ depending on whether $x>0$ or $x<0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you are already aware of the fact that for $x>0$, $f(x)=x^3$, but you have problems showing that this is differentiable.

We have 
$$f'(c) = \lim_{x \to c} \frac {f(x)-f(c)} {x-c} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(c+h)- f(c)} h\\
=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(c+h)^3-c^3}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {3hc^2 +3h^2c+h^3}{h} \\
\lim_{h\to 0}3c^2 +3hc +h^2 = 3c^2 $$

Thus $f$ is differentiable for $x>0$ and has the derivative $f'(x)=3x^2$.

Can you show that $f$ is differetiable for $x<0$?

Comment: Yes, this helped a lot. I now understand how to show that $f$ is differentiable for $x < 0$.

Comment: So what is the derivative?

Comment: for $x<0$ the derivative is $-3x^2$

Answer (score 2):

Because for all $x>0$, we have
$$(x^2|x|)'=(x^3)'=3x^2.$$